# Unable to write searched string that i find in all the files in python

Tags: python, windows

[My Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUIsW.png)Team,
My task is to find a string in all the files and write the filename, filepath and searched string all in a line in another file. so, i implemented it which prints the output as desired to stdout. however, am not able to direct it to new file. When i direct the output to new file, i am only getting last file results and none of the search results for all previous files. may be am not opening/closing file properly here is the code:

The results file is only showing the last file search parameters and nothing of the rest of the files. i want resut file to contain entry of each file.

```
resultsFile = "results.txt" 
wf = open(search_path + resultsFile, 'w')
while line != '':
    # Search for string in line
    index = line.find(search_str)
    if index != -1:
        print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")
        wf.write(fname + " " + str(search_path) + str(search_string) + " ")
    # Read next line
    line = fo.readline()
```

Output on STDOUT:

```
file1 z:/dir1/file1.json String
file2 z:/dir1/file2.json String
..
..
file10 z:/dir1/file10.json String
```

output in Results File:

```
file10 z:/dir1/file10.json String
```

Comment: Here is the Code:
 resultsFile = "results.txt"
 wf = open(search_path + resultsFile, 'w')

        while line != '':
            # Search for string in line
            index = line.find(search_str)
            if index != -1:
                print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")
                wf.write(fname + " " + str(line_no) + " " + str(index))
            # Read next line
            line = fo.readline()

Comment: Is there any chance that the code block in your question above is executed in a loop iterating over several paths for `fo`? Can you please give your example a bit more context, the issue does not seem to be in the code you posted

Comment: @shmee is right, it's probably what you are doing, so for each iteration you recreate your result file by overwriting the former one. It normal that you only see the last result ! You should append all results in one list, and at the end of the script you print it in your output file. Try to avoid keeping the output file openned for too long

Comment: here is my entire code: all i want is search a string in all files in a directory and then write the success results to a new file. my stdout on screen is good but write to new file is just showing the last file it searched.

Comment: am not able to add my code here coz it complains i have indentation problem.

Comment: I uploaded an image to my code instead. Please see if that helps

Comment: I uploaded my code as pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeatedly overwriting the result file by using 'write' mode.

```
wf = open(search_path + resultsFile, 'w')
```

Replace with the append mode as:

```
wf = open(search_path + resultsFile, 'a')
```

Comment: I tried that already but that is not the issue. even with Append mode 'a', it just writes last line. i feel somewhere my looping is not indented properly.

Comment: here is how i fixed it. may be pycharm error. i had to kill it and launch it again and then append mode that you suggested worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart my pycharm editor and started seeing append mode to work.

but i also need to know an optimized solution.

like can i write to a list and then finally write that list to a file? is that optimal?